# Entity Framework list related entity multiple levels deep

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I have a database that goes 5 related entities deep.

Users > UserStore < Store < Aisle < Shelve < Product

I have an API that I call (User user = db.Users.Find(id);) and it auto generates a nice json with the full entity. I want to still be able to pull a user by id but I don't want any of the related entities with columns Enabled = False.

I can only get to the store table but not the rest of the entities using .Include

Still having issues getting to products.

Using [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: I didn't catch the current behavior - does you method retrieve all child entities or not?

Comment: Not quite clear on your need, but if you do something like .Include(u => u.UserStore.Store.Aisle.Shelf.Product) it will retrieve all levels. If you need multiple children at the same level you can chain multiple Includes.

Comment: When I do just db.Users.Find(id) it gets all children. I don't want to get children that have a column Enabled = false(which all of the children have individually). I tried the .Include(u => u.UserStore.Store.Aisle.Shelf.Product)  but it fails. I am still trying to determine why its failing.

Comment: I do .Include(u => u.Store) works but if I try to add .Aisle " .Include(u => u.Store.Aisle) It says Aisle does exist in current context. intellisense doesn't see anything past Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something this:

```
.Include("Store.Aisle")
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get the full Entity with everything all the way down to the Product